# How do you remove all numbering except page numbering in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, titlesec, books, report

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\centering\Huge}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}
{0em}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter*{Sách tham khảo}
    \chapter{Tựa}
\end{document}
```

Note that the chapter with the asterix is not showing up. I liked having it not showing up but I need a way to delete the numbering on the chapter.

Comment: Should the numbering be removed in the actual chapter heading? Or just the table of contents?

Comment: table of contents as the chapter already have no numbers. Also all chapters, parts, ssection, subsection numbers must be removed

Comment: Ah yes - sorry missed that in your code. You can use the `titletoc` package. I'll write and answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`titletoc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package to format table of contents entries and remove the numbering using the `\titlecontents` macro.

The `\titlecontents` macro is described on pages 15 and 16 of the [`titletoc` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\centering\Huge}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0em}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\addvspace{1em}}{\bfseries}{\bfseries}{\hfill\bfseries\contentspage}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter*{Sách tham khảo}
    \chapter{Tựa}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Can you explain what these mean please?

Comment: All pages in the table of contents are displayed as 1

Comment: Oops should be `\contentspage` not `\thepage`

Comment: the `\titlecontents` macro is described on pages 15 and 16 of the [`titletoc` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf).